# C++ Best way to handle division by zero

Tags: c++, divide-by-zero

I'm writing a C++ class that stores some double values in a vector (called mpValues) and calculates their average. When constructed, the value array is empty, so performing this calculation would return 0.0/0.0.

I decided that asking for the mean of zero values is a error. Therefore, it would be best to return NaN and display an error message, so that the user is made aware of that problem.
The code looks like this:

```
double Average::CalculateAverage() const
{
    if(mpValues->size() == 0){
        std::cerr << "Instance of Average at: " << this << " contains no values.\n"
                  << "In this case the arithmetic mean is defined as NaN." <<std::endl;

        return 0.0/0.0;
    }
    else{
        ...calculate the arithmetic mean
    }
}
```

Is this a sensible approach, or do you have better suggestions? Usually, I wouldn't be so fussy, but this is a test for a job offer so I'd like to avoid bad decisions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But then how will you check for that Nan? If it's an error condition then rather throw an exception or have a boolean return parameter set to false.

Comment: @michael Why have a whole class just for an *average*? This screams of overnegineering.

Comment: Your `return 0.0/0.0;` doesn't normally return NaN... it typically generates a CPU trap/interrupt/exception (which is NOT a C++ exception that can be caught in the usual way).

Comment: Instead of this "strange" return, could you simply check if the array is empty first?

Comment: "...test for a job offer..." :)

Comment: Sometimes `0.0 / 0.0` doesn't even compile, so code containing it might require outwitting the compiler with suitable options to get it to shut up about it. In C++ you can generate a NaN where available with `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`. AFAIK in C the only portable way is `atof("NAN")`, which is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @Paul Manta: using a class was a requirement, so I had no other choice :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard options are to return NaN, throw an exception, or return an option, such as boost::optional. There are advantages and disadvantages to each, which have been reviewed in detail by numerous people. Just do not display error messages within the function, since this violates the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: +1 for mentioning three popular solutions and for suggesting not to print within the function.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your suggestions, I decided to go with an exception for now.

Answer (score 3):

You've already answered the question:

> I decided that asking for the mean of zero values is an error.

Thus, there is no need to return NaN or handle zero division. You can create your own exception class (e.g. EmptyVectorError) and throw and catch it.

Comment: +1. This is exactly the right approach to take. Create a new exception, and handle it in your code. It has exactly one meaning, and can only happen in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

this is a C++ question, so we should give a C++ answer. From the *single-responsibility principle* (mentioned by Don Reba), we conclude that reporting an error from within your function is not really appropriate. There are two main options.

**1** specify clearly that calling your `average(container)` with an empty container is *undefined behaviour* (UB). This is standard practice with many algorithms in the C++ `std` library. It allows you to ignore the possibility of an empty container and just return `sum/size()`. You may add `assert(size()>0);` (or similar) in debug mode.

**2** explicitly allow for empty containers in the API (which I think is what you wanted to). In this case, returning `sum/size()` is inappropriate. It may return `NaN` or trigger a signal, depending on the error settings, but even a `NaN` is not easy to catch (I think `isnan()` is not a standard library function). So you must somehow return the undefined result in a clean way. This can be done by throwing an appropriate exception or by returning a type, such as `boost::optional<>` (suggested by usta), which explicitly allows for an undefined value that is not an error (unlike `NaN` with `double`).

I consider throwing an exception as the most appropriate way in C++ (if you go for option 2).

Comment: `isnan` is added in C++11, for what that's worth. IEEE floating point intentionally provides ways of coding non-values, essentially it has some of the same design goals as `boost::optional`, and relieves the need for it, since IEEE was designed in part for C and assembly, not just languages as fancy as C++. But C++ doesn't mandate IEEE, so...

Comment: @SteveJessop thanks for you clarifications (in all comments in this question).

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type to `boost::optional<double>`, I'd suggest.

[Link to Doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options - either return NaN or throw an exception. What you should do, depends on the usage.

1) the client displays the mean only: then I would choose to simply return NaN. This way, the client is not forced to write error handling code for something he doesn't bother.

2) the client calculates new values using the mean: then it is difficult. By throwing an exception, you force him to handle it explicitly. This can be a good thing. On the other hand - the double value NaN can be used in calculations as far as I know. It also depends on the rest of your work. If you always use exceptions, you should use one as well. If you always use error codes, you should use NaN. If you mix - you should clean that up.

P.S.: I wouldn't write 0.0/0.0 but use [std::numeric_limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/) instead. It's easier to read.

Comment: -1 NaN is not a good idea. How to you generate one? if you call `0.0/0.0`, the behaviour depends on the error settings etc. We are talking about C++ and NaN *generating* a NaN on purpose seems a stupid idea.

Comment: "How do you generate one?" -- If the implementation supports NaN at all, then you can generate one with `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` or `signalling_NaN()`. Of course it still doesn't help with implementations that don't support NaN at all, on which you simply can't return a NaN. That's permitted by C++ but not by IEEE.